# Nullspaces relation between components and overall matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If matrix $ C = \left[ {\begin{array}{c}  A \\  B \  \end{array} } \right] $then how is N(C), the nullspace of C, related to N(A) and N(B)?

The answer was that N(C) is the intersection of N(A) and N(B), but the only explanation was $Cx = \left[ {\begin{array}{c}  Ax \\  Bx \  \end{array} } \right] = 0.$

I don't understand the explanation. I only see that the nullspaces were zero, but then doesn't all nullspaces contain 0. I didn't see how they got that N(C) was the intersection of N(A) and N(B).

Can someone describe the nullspaces in a way so that I can visualize them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Prove initially that $$N(A)\cap N(B)\subset N(C)$$
If $x\in N(A)\cap N(B)$ then $Ax=0$ and $Bx=0$. This means that
$$Cx=\left[\matrix{A\\B}\right]x=\left[\matrix{Ax\\Bx}\right]=0$$
i.e. $x\in N(C)$.

b) Prove that $N(C)\subset N(A)\cap N(B)$

If $x\in N(C)$ then 
$$Cx=\left[\matrix{A\\B}\right]x=\left[\matrix{Ax\\Bx}\right]=0$$
that yields
$Ax=0$ and $Bx=0$. This means that $x\in N(A)\cap N(B)$.

Combining a) and b) we obtain $N(C)=N(A)\cap N(B)$.

Comment: Ah I see, cause if you do A*N(B) then you'll get some non-zero number.  Then, in order to make 0, C has to be multiply by something in that exits in both N(A) and N(B), the intersection point, and that's x.